# Importing projects and Gradle not syncing

Tags: java, android

I've been walking through the Multi app screen course for google in udacity and they gave me a project to import it through android studio. the gradle is not syncing although I installed the last version. Here's the error I am getting:

Unable to load class 'javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.

Comment: This is likely due to your JAVA_HOME environmental variable.

Comment: Can you explain more how to fix the problem? @GavinWright